# GWT + XML documents with namespaces

Tags: java, xml, gwt, xpath, namespaces

I'd like to get a quick overview of available solutions (libraries, ...) that allow me to work with XML documents **with namespaces** on a DOM level - in GWT's client side.

Additionally, I'm looking for an XPath solution that can work on that DOM (even if it requires writing my own XPath Navigator).

XML parsing and serialization isn't necessary on the client - this can be done on the server.

Comment: @vtd-xml-author: Feel free to post a good alternative! On the one hand, DOM is a requirement, but maybe it could be replaced by something similar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you look for: http://realazthat.blogspot.com/2009/08/xpath-for-gwt.html

Comment: Hm, I'm looking mostly for an API like dom4j, which has real Namespace and QName objects, with methods like getNamespaceForPrefix(), etc. http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/Element.html This is, because we need to convert an existing project to GWT, and it makes heavy use of QName objects etc. It also uses XPath a lot (with a custom Navigator implementation) - so maybe your suggestion could be useful - thanks!

Comment: After doing some more searching, it looks, as if nothing like that exists. It's not too big a problem, because most of what we need can also be done with com.google.gwt.xml.client.* I will accept your answer - because at the moment it's probably impossible to find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Feel free to take a look at Totoe: http://code.google.com/p/totoe/

It's an alternative XML parser with XPath and namespace support for GWT. Basically it is a GWT port of Sarissa (http://dev.abiss.gr/sarissa/).

HTH Harald